# replaceregexp ant not inserting tabulation

Tags: regex, ant

I want to replace a tabulation when I have a match in a file. I have this code:

```
<property name="line.separator" location="\r" />
<property name="tab.separator" location="\t" />

<target name="replace">
    <replaceregexp 
        match='@WebMethod([\s\S]*?(?=public))public\s+(\w+)\s+(\w*)[\s\S]+?(?=\))[\s\S]+?(?=MSE)(\w+)\s+(\w*)[\s\S+]+?(?=throws)throws\s+(\w*)' 
        replace='@WebMethod(operationName="\$4")${line.separator}${tab.separator}@RequestWrapper(localName = "\$3")${line.separator}\r@ResponseWrapper(localName = "\$2")${line.separator}\rpublic \$2 \$3\(${line.separator}\r\r\$4 \$5)${line.separator}\r\rthrows MSFWebServiceException' flags="g,m">
        <fileset dir="${project.dir}" />
    </replaceregexp>
```

But the part of
 @WebMethod(operationName="\$4")${line.separator}${tab.separator}@RequestWrapper

returns this:

```
@WebMethod(operationName="MSEPDetalleFigPartDTO")
C:t@RequestWrapper
```

So the \n goes ok, but the \t doesn't work because it replace the \t with C:t instead of a tabulation.

Any help would be appreciate.

kindest regards

Answer (score 2):

This is cause by `location` instead of `value` and `\t` instead of `&#x9;`:

```xml
<property name="tab.separator" location="\t" />
```

instead of

```xml
<property name="tab.separator" value="&#x9;" />
```

The property `line.separator` is already set (because it is an [Ant built-in property](https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#built-in-props)), so your first line is just ignored.

`location="\t"` means the file location of the file `t` in the root directory, in your case it is the drive `C:`